# How to create a flexible nav.php that does not need to be maintained by a coder

Tags: php, uinavigationbar

I found a link I like: User-friendly Contextual Navigation with Simple PHP Includes http://brainstormsandraves.com/archives/2006/09/27/navigation/

But things there are hard-coded. How can things be made easier?
Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: There is the framework `Stacey` that implements this. https://github.com/kolber/stacey

Comment: @Ross, thanks. Is it easy to install? How? What PHP versions does it support? I think I only want a part of what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution like this might be good:

In a new file, define an array:
$pages = array( 'Home' => '/index.php', 'News' => '/news.php' );

Then a function that prints the menu

```
function print_menu() {
  foreach($pages as $name=>$url) {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $url) print $name;
    else print '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$name.'</a>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for a 100% noob question: A) I define both in the same file? B) How do I use this function from another file, whether .php or .html? Is `$name` a global variable that is defined for each PHP page? Is it automatic, or does it need to be defined? Is there a better name such as $pageName, or is that the acceptable standard?

Comment: Beat me to it. A nice clean simple solution. I've used something like this in my projects before.

Comment: I would define them both in the same file.  To use this function on every page, use the PHP keyword 'include' (plenty of info on the PHP website), then call print_menu() where you want the menu.  Even though you are including the new file, you will still need the <?php tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with javascript at clientside. Which is way easier and does not require any modification code at server side. 
I am going to use jquery here -

```
function OnLoad(){
     // Assuming the links are in the format http://example.com/section/. 
     // I am stripping out the the 4th (3 in the [] below) column when split with /'s 
     location = document.location.href.split("/")[3];
     $('li.menuitems a[href*='+location+']').each( function() {
          $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
      });
});
```

<strike>I really need to work on my jquery :( . This is just a pseudo code and I assure you that this is achievable</strike> 
**Edit:** Worked on getting the jquery working..

Code at http://pastie.org/1329224 . Sample page for "about" at [GoogAppspot](http://savedbythegoog.appspot.com/?id=b0db1d34ca4a66482c1046df7f3543d5fb4f4114)

Comment: I have not used `jQuery` before. If you beef and clean this up, this can be a winner answer.